# Excel VBA: Array not empty but has no value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a global array named myArray.
In this array is stored information taken from another file.
The procedure handles the data stored in myArray, and it works fine.

However, when I launch the procudre a 2nd time, I have a condition where myArray is tested:
IsEmpty(myArray) returns false
So apparantly it's not empty. So when I type in the immediate window this:
UBound(myArray), I get an error message.
So it's not empty, but it doesn't have any values.
Also, IsNull(myArray) returns false.

This makes my code not work properly, because it's supposed to see if myArray is empty, and if it isn't then it accesses one by one the values of myArray. Obviously this causes an error the 2nd time around.

I tired 'Erase myArray' at the end of the procedure, that doesn't help.

Any clues?

Thanks,

Edit: Sample code:

```
    Global myArray As Variant

    Sub tryMe()
    For i = 0 To 10
        If IsEmpty(myArray) Then
            ReDim myArray(0)
            myArray(0) = i
        Else
        tempVal = UBound(myArray)
        ReDim Preserve myArray(tempVal + 1)
        myArray(tempVal + 1) = i
        End If

    Next i
    MsgBox UBound(myArray)

    End Sub
```

Comment: You say "launch the procedure a second time" does this mean the current runtime has ended?  Once the runtime has completed the script, all variables lose their value.  Please clarify.

Comment: Show your actual code (shortened to just include the relevant parts)

Comment: TheGreatCO: "Once the runtime has completed the script, all variables lose their value" = Actually no. If I had set the variable scope with the Dim statement, yes it would loose its value at the end. But since I'm using a global variable, it keeps the value.

Comment: I can run this example code multiple times and not able to replicate the error.

Comment: `So when I type in the immediate window this: UBound(myArray)` What exact error message do you get?

Comment: This function might help test what's wrong with your `myArray`. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx

Comment: I just ran your code - it displays 10 in the first run, 21 in the second run, etc.. If I press the Stop button, the array is reset as expected, i.e. next run will return 10. So it works fine here. What happens on your machine?

Comment: You're right David, I forgot to include this last line before the "End Sub" statement:Erase myArray. If I don't include it, there's no error like you noticed, but the values keep adding & I don't want that. When you run the code with this extra line, you get : "Runtime error 9", Subscript out of range. (because it's trying to access the number of items in myArray, which has nothing but is not empty...)

Comment: Use the @UserName notation to address your comments to people. This way they will get notified by SO of your comment! Only the owner of a post will be notified by default!

Comment: @DavidZemens : Thanks for that link, it actually solved my problem. I inserted that function in my code as a test condition, thereby preventing the runtime error. Thanks!